# Using Windows Phone WIde Tiles with Cordova

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

How do you specify an image for WideTile on the Windows Phone when using Cordova?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this option [Wide Live Tile] is not supported at present time. I'll create a feature request for WP8 and WP7.8. Most likely updated version of LiveTiles plugin will be landed to the following place

https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-wp8/tree/master/plugins/www/plugins/LiveTiles

**UPDATE**

Updated version could be found here

https://github.com/sgrebnov/incubator-cordova-wp8/tree/master/plugins/www/plugins/LiveTiles

Sample usage

```
        navigator.plugins.liveTiles.updateAppTile(success, fail, {
            title: document.getElementById('title').value,
            image: 'Images/appbar.next.rest.png',
            count: document.getElementById('count').value,
            backTitle: 'Back title',
            backContent: 'Back side',
            backImage: 'Images/appbar.close.rest.png',
            smallImage: 'Images/appbar.save.rest.png',
            wideContent: 'This is wide content',
            wideImage: 'Images/appbar.stop.rest.png',
            wideBackImage: 'Images/appbar.feature.video.rest.png'
        });
```